# java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid block type

Tags: java, spring-boot, cloud-foundry, cloudfoundry-uaa

When java spring boot application jar is trying to push to cloud(cloudfoundry). getting following exception.

```
Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.springframework.cloud.CloudConnector: Error reading configuration file
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:232)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.parse(ServiceLoader.java:309)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$200(ServiceLoader.java:185)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.hasNextService(ServiceLoader.java:357)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:393)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:474)
    at org.springframework.cloud.CloudFactory.scanCloudConnectors(CloudFactory.java:91)
    at org.springframework.cloud.CloudFactory.<init>(CloudFactory.java:35)
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.CloudScanHelper.initializeCloud(CloudScanHelper.java:82)
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.CloudScanHelper.registerServiceBeans(CloudScanHelper.java:55)
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.java.ServiceScanConfiguration.registerBeanDefinitions(ServiceScanConfiguration.java:22)
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.java.CloudScanConfiguration.registerBeanDefinitions(CloudScanConfiguration.java:22)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsFromRegistrars(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:352
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.j
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:116)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:333)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:243)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:273)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:678)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:520)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:760)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:306)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1185)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1174)
    at com.ge.og.pii.ap.rest.Application.main(Application.java:24)
    ... 8 more
 Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid block type
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:164)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.ZipInflaterInputStream.read(ZipInflaterInputStream.java:52)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:161)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:324)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:389)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.parseLine(ServiceLoader.java:255)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.parse(ServiceLoader.java:307)
    ... 34 more
```

Can somebody help me. No clue why suddenly it is throwing this exception. previously it was worked well.

Thanks in advace.

Comment: Is the issue fixed still?

Comment: Personally, I use `gradle` and deleting its cache fixed the issue.